# Particles Have Ugly Dynamic Painting

Tags: particles, collision, dynamic-paint

I am rather new to 3D animation and Blender and am following this tutorial. https://youtu.be/0koL5NGBaA0.  The goal is to animate halfway realistic rain sliding down a window.  So far it has been well explained and I have had little trouble with completing it.  The only issue is that the trails the raindrops leave behind on the glass are quite off.  As shown in the attached photo the trails seem to be made of many little circles rather than a smooth line.

The trails are created through the dynamic paint property, with the raindrop particles acting as a brush on the glass object.  I believe that the issue is with the dynamic painting because if I enter GIMP and manually paint over the paths with pure white the issue is solved to a degree.  This does not look nearly as good as it does in the video and I do not have the time or skill to make every frame look good manually through GIMP.  I have followed every step of the tutorial to the best of my ability and have gone back over it a few times but cannot seem to find the source of this issue.  I have been trying to solve the problem myself but I do not know enough about Blender to figure this out on my own.  If there is anything else needed to solve this issue I will happily give it.  I would very much appreciate any help with this problem, thank you.
[image: Screenshot of Shading Page with the described error.+]

Comment: Increasing the substeps should help, at the top right of your property panel in the screenshot. Anit-Aliasing could also help, I do not know where that setting is.

Comment: Hint: "This does not look nearly as good as it does in the video" -> yep, because often the maker of the tutorial shows in the beginning a "teaser" and sometimes even in-between results he made before with other blend files. So it is always a good idea to scroll to the end of the video and compare, whether teaser and end result are looking "similar" and not the difference between a Hollywoodmovie and some animation which could have made a 4 year old kid - so don't always trust the  video maker! ;)

Comment: @Phönix64 Thank you for getting back to me.  I brought the sub-steps up to 20 which appears to be the maximum and the problem is persisting.  Any idea what else could be causing this issue with the dynamic painting?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the response.  I certainly don't expect what is shown at the start of the video to be the result but I would like to figure out what the issue is with the steps I have taken for future reference.  The tutorial shows the results of what he actually did in the video around 26:15 and the difference between his results and mine are striking.  I don't expect anything particularly amazing but it would be nice to improve my knowledge by understanding what I did wrong.

Comment: did you try increasing the subdivision levels?

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different method than that in the video, killing the particles on impact and then using the drip effect to create the smeare downwards. In the material, the wetmap is used.
I also increased the Particle and dynamic paint substeps to 20 and turned on anti-aliasing as well as increased the texture size to 2048:
[image]
[image]

Hope it helped